# How Can I decrease the distance in the TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout02"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >

            <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
                <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="62px">


                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/VisualPane" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     />

                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/HTMLPane" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        />  
                </FrameLayout>
            </TabHost>
        </FrameLayout>
```

How Can I decrease this distance?
[image: http://s47.radikal.ru/i118/1101/92/6844493547b4.jpg]
I have tried to change the attribute

```
android:paddingTop="62px"
```

But it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `android:layout_height = "wrap_content"` instead of `"fill_parent"`
Then you can play with the paddingTop value also :)